# How to use async code inside map() (Flutter, Firestore)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a group chat app with Flutter and the Firestore Plugin. Getting the data from the database and converting the snapshot into a List of Messages works totally fine. But now I want to convert the uid from the database into the username (the uids and their usernames are saved in the db). This is my code:

```
final CollectionReference messagesCollection =
    Firestore.instance.collection('messages');

final CollectionReference usersCollection =
    Firestore.instance.collection('users');

Future<String> getUsernameByUID(String _uid) async {
  String username =
      await usersCollection.document(uid).get().then((querySnapshot) {
    return (querySnapshot.data["username"]);
  });
  return username;
}

List<Message> _messagesFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot){
  return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {

    String username = await getUsernameByUID(doc.data["uid"]);

    return Message(
      text: doc.data["text"] ?? "",
      username: username ?? "",
      time: doc.data["time"] ?? "",
    );
  }).toList();
}


Stream<List<Message>> get messages {
  return messagesCollection
      .orderBy("time")
      .snapshots()
      .map(_messagesFromSnapshot);
}
```

The problem is in this line, because I cannot run this async code inside of the map().

```
String username = await getUsernameByUID(doc.data["uid"]);
```

Is there a solution to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`async` functions must return a `Future`, so adding `async` keyword to your callback means that your `List.map()` call must now return a `List` of `Future`s.

You can convert a `List<Future<Message>>` to a `List<Message>` by using [`Future.wait`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-async/Future/wait.html):

```dart
Future<List<Message>> _messagesFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) async {
  var futures = snapshot.documents.map((doc) async {
    String username = await getUsernameByUID(doc.data["uid"]);

    return Message(
      text: doc.data["text"] ?? "",
      username: username ?? "",
      time: doc.data["time"] ?? "",
    );
  });

  return await Future.wait(futures);
}
```

Of course, `Future.wait` returns a `Future` and must be `await`ed, so now `_messagesFromSnapshot` must be `async` as well.  Asynchrony is contagious, and that then would affect any callers of `_messagesFromSnapshot`.

Since the `messages` getter returns a `Stream` and is already asynchronous, I believe that you instead can use [`Stream.asyncMap`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-async/Stream/asyncMap.html):

```dart
Stream<List<Message>> get messages {
  return messagesCollection
      .orderBy("time")
      .snapshots()
      .asyncMap(_messagesFromSnapshot);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need is [Future.forEach](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-async/Future/forEach.html) method. it iterates over a list and waits until all the async methods to finish before moving on to the next item in the list.

```
Future<List<Message>> _messagesFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) async {
  List<Message> _messages = [];
  await Future.forEach(snapshot.documents, (doc) async {
    String username = await getUsernameByUID(doc.data["uid"]);
    _messages.add(
       Message(
        text: doc.data["text"] ?? "",
        username: username ?? "",
        time: doc.data["time"] ?? "",)
     );   
    });   
  return _messages; 
}
```

Here is an example [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/8d0584ac8ae2c8e5e147946cca0e0498)

Comment: Because `_messagesFromSnapshot` is `async`, it now must return a `Future<List<Message>>`, and the callers of `_messagesFromSnapshot` must be updated accordingly (and their callers, and so on).

Comment: You can't escape from that

Comment: I didn't claim that you could escape from it.  My point is that your answer is incomplete since it doesn't mention what changes are necessary are in the callers of `_messagesFromSnapshot`.