# Flutter: Error: 'await' can only be used in 'async' or 'async*' methods. even thought the method is async

Tags: flutter

I have this method:

```
Future<AppUser> _getUser(String documentId) async {
    var document = await firestore.collection('customers').doc(documentId);
    document.get().then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
          print(documentSnapshot.data());
    });
    AppUser bruceUser = AppUser(userId: 'user006',);

    return bruceUser;   
}
```

And below it, I have a variable that uses this method:

```
AppUser _user = await _getUser(document.id);
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
Error: 'await' can only be used in 'async' or 'async*' methods.
```

What am I doing wrong here? I don't want to change _user to Future, because it will complicate the code further, so why doesn't the await work?

Comment: What about the function you are calling `AppUser _user = await _getUser(document.id);`? Is it async?

Comment: @JustCode, no. it's a `snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document){` function. I tried making it async, but it returns `Error: The argument type 'List<Future<UstaTile>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'`

Comment: Then it is the problem, why don't you try `_getUser(document.id).then((user){//code here})`

Comment: @JustCode do i put the snapshot in `then`?

Comment: Please check the answer. I think it will clear your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_getUser()` is an asnyc function but not the calling function.
The error you are getting states that, `await` was used in a non-async function.
If you have difficulty in converting the caller function to async, try using `then` as follows.

```
snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
    _getUser(document.id).then((user) {
          //code here
    });
}
```

In summary, there are two solutions for this

1. Convert the caller function to `async`.
2. Use `_getUser().then((user){});`

Comment: because of the await in _getUser(), it takes too long to run and I get ```"Column's children must not contain any null values, but a null value was found at index 0"```. I put a print statement in getUser() inside `document.get()` and one before `_getUser(document.id).then((user) {` and inside of it. The one before prints, then I get an error and then the one inside prints and lastly the on inside _getUser() prints.

Comment: Are you using the data from this callback to build a `Column` widget? In such a case you have to either use a future builder or hold the column build process until you receive the data from the async callback.

Comment: How can I hold the column build process?

Comment: With help of a `StatefulWidget` and a single boolean value, you can archive the same. Based on the boolean value you can display a column data or a loading widget.

Comment: I'm trying, but again didn't work. Because ```snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {``` is inside column, it doesn't get called.

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58978730/how-to-use-async-code-inside-map-flutter-firestore helps?