# How can I resolve a future within an async* stream in dart?

Tags: asynchronous, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a stream of posts that works fine but I want to check whether the current user likes a particular post. To implement the latter, I have to get info from Firestore which is a future. I have tried using yield* but it doesn't work. My code is as below;

```
CollectionReference posts = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts');

String userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;

  Stream<List<Post>> get allPosts async* {
    yield* posts.snapshots().map((snapShot) => snapShot.docs.map((document) {
          DocumentSnapshot isLikedByCurrentUser = await FirebaseFirestore //The await here is erroneous and doesnt work
              .instance
              .collection('likes')
              .doc(this.userId + '_' + document.id)
              .get();
          return Post.fromJson(
              document.id, document.data(), isLikedByCurrentUser.exists);
        }).toList());
  }
```

Comment: What type is `snapShot.docs`? Is it an iterable or a stream?

Comment: It's an iterable.

Answer (score 0):

This is more complicated than it needs to be. I'd unwrap the `map` calls to `for` loops:

```dart
  Stream<List<Post>> get allPosts async* {
    for (var snapshot in posts.snapshots()) {
      var element = <Post>[]; 
      for (var document in shapshot.docs) {
        DocumentSnapshot isLikedByCurrentUser = await FirebaseFirestore
              .instance
              .collection('likes')
              .doc(this.userId + '_' + document.id)
              .get();
          element.add(Post.fromJson(
              document.id, document.data(), isLikedByCurrentUser.exists));
      }
      yield element;
    }
  }
```

You can even use a list literal, if you don't mind inlining the `isLikedByCurrentUser` variable:

```dart
Stream<List<Post>> get allPosts async* {
  for (var snapshot in posts.snapshots()) {
    yield <Post>[
      for (var document in shapshot.docs)
        Post.fromJson(
            document.id,
            document.data(),
            (await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('likes')
                    .doc(this.userId + '_' + document.id)
                    .get())
                .exists)
    ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have re-written it based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58981983/10123373) by [jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179715/jamesdlin).

```
Future<List<Post>> _postFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) async {
    var futures = snapshot.docs.map((doc) async {
      DocumentSnapshot isLikedByCurrentUser = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('likes')
          .doc(this.userId + '_' + doc.id)
          .get();
      return Post.fromJson(
          doc.id, doc.data(), isLikedByCurrentUser.exists);
    }).toList();

    return await Future.wait(futures);
  }

  Stream<List<Post>> get allPosts {
    return posts.snapshots().asyncMap(_postFromSnapshot);
  }
```